# How can i call a variable in my public class on vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have this public class

```
    Public Class commonSettings
        Dim etcString As String = "some string"
    End Class
```

How can i call **etcString** and use it entirely on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Public` modifier.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx#methodscope_topic3

If you want to be able to access it without an instance, use the `Shared` modifier as well.

Edit: Code sample

```
Public Class commonSettings
    Public Shared etcString As String = "some string"
End Class
```

Comment: Bad answer. Explain instead why this is a bad idea.

Comment: I don't have anything against globally static variables. In some cases they aren't the best idea, but overall they aren't the end of the world _if used properly_.

Comment: Global *statics* are kind of a different case. They too have problems though, which it might be worth addressing.

Comment: Konrad, iirc in VB.Net Shared variables are static. @wpleet what do you mean "call this"? You don't normally "call" a variable.

Comment: @jli i mean how will i use it on my code? I'm creating a connection string for my MySQL database and i dont want to declare it every time i connect to DB. What's the best practice for this kind of situation?

Comment: From anywhere within the namespace, you can access it with commonSettings.etcString.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, OP did not ask about proper design; only about specific implementation details. Bad design or not, MS provides the "Shared" keyword so this answer is appropriate

Comment: @jli Yes, `Shared` = static. That’s not my point. My point is: Public static readonly (!) variables: oh well, if you must. Public member variables: always horse poo.

Answer (score 4):

Make it accessible through a public property

```
Public Class commonSettings
    Dim etcString As String = "some string"
    Public Property mETCString(ByVal value as String) As String
         Get
              return etcString
         End Get
         Set(value as String)
              etcString = value
         End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

OR if using VB 10 (VS 2010) - use an Auto-Implemented Property

```
Public Class commonSettings
    Public Property etcString As String = "some string"
End Class
```

Or make the variable directly accesible

```
Public Class commonSettings
    Public etcString As String = "some string"
End Class
```

However as Konrad mentioned creating a public variable isn't the best idea. The reasonings behind this are as follows:

- If you change the internal implementation you are potentially breaking external dependencies.
- You can't use DataBinding on a variable
- Variables are seen as more of an implementation level item whereas properties define more of the interface to an object.

Comment: Bad answer. Explain instead why having public variables is a bad idea.

Comment: @Konrad can you think of anything that I missed there.

Comment: @msarchet I'm creating a connection string for my MySQL database and i dont want to declare it every time i connect to DB. What's the best practice for this kind of situation? Declaring it as Public will fit to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to msarchet's answer (which is probably the correct answer for this question "How do I make a member less private"), if you are looking for the variable to be stateless, (meaning you don't have to have an instance of the surrounding class) and you don't want it to be a shared member (so you won't have to write classname.membername), you may be looking for a Module.

You make a module like this:

```
Module GlobalVars
    Public etcString as String = "Some String"
End Module
```

Then call it from anywhere in the program simply by saying

```
etcString = "New String"
```

Comment: A module essentially compiles into a static class with static members, so it's no different that the other answers to this question which mention static members. ;) Also, as Konrad has been saying, explain why globals are a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, essentially the same as static, but called slightly more easily through code.  Globals are obviously bad because you can accidentally mess a lot of variable names and stuff up with scope definition, and the variable never goes out of scope so the garbage collector never collects it until your program is shut down.  The question wasn't asking whether globals were bad or not, it asked how to use them to accomplish a goal.  Therefore, I did not feel the need to explain why they were bad.